# Is it possible to silence other alerts when alert "host down" appear?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter, prometheus-alertmanager

I use prometheus and alertmanager to monitor few servers, and every time that server go down i get bunch of alerts ex. "Nginx down" "Docker down" along side alert "Host down", and that create bunch of spam in pagerduty and email. I would like to not get alerts for specific services while i already got alert that whole server is not working.

Is there any possible way to do it in prometheus or alertmanager config?

Answer (score 0):

With Alertmanager you can inhibit alerts based on other alerts. There're several ways to achieve that.

One way could be to define the "host down" alerts as "critical" and the other "xxx down" alerts as "warning", then inhibit the warnings when you have criticals:

```
inhibit_rules:
  - source_match:
      severity: critical
    target_match:
      severity: warning
    equal: [alertname, instance]
```

Comment: This syntax is deprecated. There are two arrays now: `source_matchers` and `target_matchers`. https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#inhibit_rule